# Output redirection ownership

Tags: system-calls, strace

When i execute `cat file.txt > newfile.txt`, which process or program is executing the syscall?

I've tried using `strace cat file.txt > newfile.txt` to identify this, but havent been successful in identifying who is executing the syscall, only thats its been called. If there is an easy way to figure this out, help would be appreciated!

Comment: The redirection is done solely by the shell you're running `cat` in.   `cat` has no involvement in the redirection part of the command, it just reads file.txt and dumps it to stdout.

Comment: @cas Yea, I aware of this  -- but is there a distinguishable way to identify that the shell is executing the write syscall here?

Comment: you could strace the shell.

Comment: You should try this `strace bash -c 'cat file.txt > newfile.txt'`. You are merely strace-ing `cat file.txt`

Comment: `cat` is executing the `write` syscall. `shell` is opening the file, with appropriate options like Create and Truncate. When `shell` creates the process that will become `cat`, the child inherits an open file descriptor (probably fd3), and moves that onto fd1 so that `cat` can later use it as stdout.